# Mobile Design for Mattress Measurement Scenario

Tags: iphone, mobile

I am creating a mobile app which allows me to measure the dimensions for the mattress. Currently, I am using the following design:

[image]

As you can note that using this kind of user interface on a mobile device is cumbersome. I am looking for ideas on how this control/interface can be improved for mobile devices? The width and height component has additional fraction measurements components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIPickerView-SW1) to let the user change the width and height fields. When the user taps on one of the fields, show a picker with two columns: inches and fractions. Or, set both length and width at the same time with four columns:

[image]

This is the kind of thing that a picker view is designed for.

**Update:**

> How would it be possible to have a single picker view with 4 columns where Width and Height can have two different values. Usually all the values in the picker are related to a single entity.

Aren't these values all related to a single entity also? They're all attributes of the mattress size. It would be strange to have a picker where the columns weren't all somehow related to the same thing, but you can define the scope of that thing (e.g. mattress size). Technically, all that's necessary to make the picker work is for the delegate to know what to put in each column and how to interpret the user's selection.

Comment: Thanks! Currently, we are using a picker view and it does not provide a good experience on the mobile device. Since there are 4 drop downs and it takes time to select those. So, I was looking for a different option. Just to be clear the current implementation uses PickerView.

Comment: You could do all four values with four columns in a single picker, giving only 1 thing to select.

Comment: Now, that I think about it! How would it be possible to have a single picker view with 4 columns where Width and Height can have two different values. Usually all the values in the picker are related to a single entity.

Comment: I think maybe you were talking about a separate picker view for width and height each containing two measurement selections.

Comment: Setting length and width separately seems a little more clear, but setting both at once would be a little faster and shouldn't be a problem if the user will use the app more than once in a blue moon.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb!! Awesome! Do you know any JavaScript libraries that will allow me to create such a picker view control.

Comment: Me too :) This would be so easy if it was native but it is a mobile website so no options there!